# How to create a shortcut to a Windows partition folder?

Tags: linux, mount, partition, dual-boot

I often need to mount my windows partition (which mounts to the `C:/` location by default) and I have to navigate to `partition/Users/[username]/Desktop` manually.

I think I can't just create a shortcut in Debian because the absolute path will change every time I mount the partition.

How can I create a shortcut that lives in C:/ and points to the desktop so every time I mount it from Linux I can just double click it and go to the folder I want?

Thanks

Comment: If it's mounted somewhere in the directory tree, you can access it like any other directory. It doesn't matter on which partition it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to think in terms of the directory paths in your Debian system. Let's assume the Windows `C:\` gets mounted as `/media/c`. It doesn't really matter but we'll use that as the example. Let's further assume that in the Windows context you want to create a shortcut (symbolic link) to that partition's `\Users\roaima\Desktop`.

```
cd /media/c
ln -s Users/roaima/Desktop roaima_Desktop
```

That's it. The symbolic link (shortcut) is called `roaima_Desktop`, and you can now `cd /media/c/roaima_Desktop`.

If the mount point changes to `/mnt/wincdrive` you can still `cd /mnt/wincdrive/roaima_Desktop` because the symbolic link was created with a path relative to its starting point: it contains only the path necessary to get from the point it was created to a specific subdirectory, and has no information about the directory path associated with the mount point itself.

The symbolic link will not work in the Windows context. It will appear in the filesystem as `roaima_Desktop` but Windows will not be able to do anything with it. (NTFS has symbolic links but Windows does not.)

Comment: Windows does have symbolic links (see `mklink` command in Windows), I used them quite a few times. However I guess they are implemented differently than Linux symbolic links, so Windows definitely will not understand a symbolic link created in Linux.

Comment: @raj I think that `mklink` creates junctions rather than symbolic links - either way though, the `ln -s` will create an item on an NTFS filesystem that Linux can understand but that Windows cannot. I haven't tested whether Linux can understand junctions created by `mklink` - that's an interesting question in itself: I wonder if `mklink` would satisfy the OP's requirement

Comment: Yeah I don't care if the link works in Windows or not, I just one that's permanent and works on Linux. I will try it now, thanks :) Looks like it's working, I'm accepting the answer. Thanks again.